# Why would I not want to use intermediate representation (IR) in Solidity v0.8.13 and above?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, bytecode, optimization, yul

In [Solidity v0.8.13](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.8.13), the intermediate representation (IR) codegen feature has been brought out of the experimental stage. We can now run the compiler with `--via-ir` flag to enable Yul IR, which makes the compiler generate
Yul code before generating the final EVM bytecode.

This has lots of benefits, like enabling powerful optimizations. For example, IR makes `x != 0` have the same gas cost as `x > 0` (with `x` being an `uint256`).

My question is: is there a reason not to use `--via-ir` all the time? When would I not want to use it?

Answer (score 2):

It takes much longer to compile with Yul.