# Translate EVM to YUL

Tags: solidity, evm, yul

Is there any method to retrieve compilable YUL from EVM byte code?

I've found `EVMToEWasmTranslator.cpp` at Solidity main repo, but it seems to be designed to translate between YUL dialects.

Maybe there is some possibility to achieve this via LLVM ([evmjit](https://github.com/cd1m0/evm2llvm) or [EthSema](https://github.com/ethsema/ethsema-paper))?
There is also some paper (Solidify, An LLVM pass to compile LLVM IR into Solidity).

I don't need the target to be human-readable, just recompilable.

Comment: have you checked online decompiler at Etherscan? awesome thing, checks input signatures vs ethereum signature database and labels the function as it is coded in the original source

Comment: Maybe [via IR](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131115/why-would-i-not-want-to-use-intermediate-representation-ir-in-solidity-v0-8-13) helps.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, I wouldn't ask this question if I had access to Sol source.

Comment: @Nulik, unfortunately all existing decompilers (this one included) doesn't provide full semantics for the purpose of recompilation.

Comment: @AlexandrTenson then I would suggest digging into machine learning decompiling algorithms since Yul is also high level language.

Answer (score 0):

[This tool](https://library.dedaub.com/decompile) is not perfect, but at least able to recompile some examples.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[heimdall](https://github.com/Jon-Becker/heimdall-rs), *an advanced EVM toolkit which aims to make dealing with smart contracts on EVM based chains easier*, provides a module to decompile EVM bytecode into Solidity.

More info about the `decompile` module can be found [here](https://github.com/Jon-Becker/heimdall-rs/wiki/Modules#decompile).
The wiki also provides examples, see [here](https://github.com/Jon-Becker/heimdall-rs/wiki/Examples#decompile).